# Do I need to check for log_username and session username in CGI::Session?

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

This code checks whether `$user` which comes from the login form and `$session_user` which comes from the `cgisess_*` file stored in the `/tmp` directory are defined. One of the cases is when `$user` and `$session_user` are both `undefined`. Is that a valid case?
Also is there a need to do a `$session(flush)`? Wouldn't that delete the very same session that was just created?
I just want to make sure that it makes sense because I don't fully understand CGI::Session despite reading quite a bit about it.

```
# CGI::Session object for session handling                                                                                                                                                                                                      
my $session = CGI::Session->new(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>'/tmp/authorize'});
my $session_user = $session->param('username');

if (defined $user) {
  $session->param('username', $user);
  $session->flush();
  my $cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name  => $session->name,
                             -value => $session->id );
  print $cgi->header( -cookie=>$cookie );
  # CGI::Session::Auth object for authentication                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  my $auth = CGI::Session::Auth::CSV->new({CGI => $cgi, Session => $session});
  $auth->authenticate();
  if ($auth->loggedIn) {
    print <<HTML;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<h3>This is the website AA $user</h3>                                                                                                                                                                                                             
</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
HTML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  } else {
    show_header("Iniciar sessão/Criar conta AA", "?");
    show_main("login");
    show_footer();
    show_rest();
  }
} else {
  if (!(defined $session_user)) {
    $session->flush();
    my $cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name  => $session->name,
                               -value => $session->id );
    print $cgi->header( -cookie=>$cookie );
    show_header("Iniciar sessão/Criar conta BB", "?");
    show_main("login");
    show_footer();
    show_rest();
  } else {
    $user = $session->param('username');
    $session->flush();
    my $cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name  => $session->name,
                               -value => $session->id );
    print $cgi->header( -cookie=>$cookie );
    print <<HTML;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<h3>This is the website CC $session_user</h3>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
HTML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is checking if `$user` and `$session_user` is both undefined? Yes, it is. Then, the `flush()` method is explicitly writing changes to storage (disk). the `params()` method is used to obtain the user for the new session. Flush is an important step because it ensures that any changes made to the session data is written back to the session storage immediately.